# How can I send an email message with an attachment, but without any plaintext body using System.NET.mail?

Tags: .net, email, mime-types, multipart, system.net.mail

Our application is sending our emails with Word attachments using System.Net.Mail. We have empty-string as our plaintext bodies. The application receiving these email messages sends them as faxes, with the result that the fax machines prints an unnecessary blank page for the empty plain-text body.

Is there any way to force System.Net.Mail to not send any body at all?

Alternatively, setting the email to use the multipart/alternative mime type (it's currently using multipart/mixed) seems like it should fix this problem, but I don't think it's supported. Any ideas for how to make System.Net.Mail do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That maybe a flaw in the fax system, have you checked the resulting mails format, in that on arrival, is there perhaps blank lines, or is it just that the fax defaults to adding a blank page for the blank email?

Comment: I have checked the source of the email: there are no whitespace characters or newlines in it, just the mime-header. I've gone with your advice and passed this issue onto the providers of the fax system to see if they have a solution.

Comment: It would seem the right thing to do :) hope they pull through